# How to disable Google Map MouseOver

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I am making an aspx page to track vehicles. The only thing I am sticking with is that I don't know how to remove tooltip text from google markers.
The data is displaying correctly.

[image]

In the image above, (1) is being shown when I am taking my cursor on marker image and (2) is coming when I am clicking on the marker.

I want to hide (1). How to do that?

I am using the following code:

```
function initMap() {
        var image = '../images/FireTruck.png';
        var markers = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString() %>');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title,
                icon: image
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.title);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the `title` property of the marker (that is what sets the tooltip).

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: data.title,  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< REMOVE THIS
    icon: image
});
```